# x-editable datepicker Year/ Month only

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, x-editable

I have modified the jQuery UI datepicker to only display year and month. I have used these javascript events to handle the data: http://jsfiddle.net/2puz2/4/

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm',
    currentText: 'This Month',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        var month = $('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected').val();
        var year = $('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected').val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        var setMonth = ('0' + (parseInt(month) + 1)).slice(-2);
        $(this).val('Start: ' +  year + '-' + setMonth);
    },
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
            var dateOutOfDesc = datestr.match(/\d{4}\-\d{2}/);
            var dateparts = dateOutOfDesc[0].split('-');
            var year = dateparts[0];
            var month = dateparts[1];
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month-1, 1));
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month-1, 1));
        }
    }
});
```

Now I would like to use x-editable to edit this date, but I cannot figure out how to attach these callback functions to the builtin datepicker. I've tried

```
editable.input.options.datepicker.beforeShow = function(input, inst) {
...
```

See this http://jsfiddle.net/L2Z9Q/18/

But it seems like this is after the datepicker has already been initialised.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `onChangeMonthYear` event (fired when month or year is changed - [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear)) to update the datepicker date instead of `onClose`. I don't have an explanation why the `onClose` isn't fired...

```
$('#yearmonth').editable({
    pk: 1,
    format: 'yyyy-mm',    
    viewformat: 'yyyy-mm',    
    datepicker: {            
        onChangeMonthYear: function(  year,  month,  inst){
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month-1, 1));
        }
    }
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Z9Q/20/)

Comment: very very close! Only problem is that I actually have format M-y and it is not being picked up by viewformat http://jsfiddle.net/L2Z9Q/21/ I have checked the tokens on here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: You mean that the dropdownlist of year is in 4 digits and not in 2?

Comment: Hi, no, it just ignores what is in the editable cell, instead it defaults to the current month/ year. This is with 4 digit year, but no difference. http://jsfiddle.net/L2Z9Q/23/

Comment: Set the data-value attribute together with the format property (has to contain a day I think). To show the date use the viewformat property.  http://jsfiddle.net/L2Z9Q/24/